# Select many 2 fields with a same type

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

(Sorry if the title misleading. Feel free to edit it.)

Straight to the example :

```
public class A
{
    public ObservableCollection<B> Bs;

    public List<D> getSelectedDs()
    {
        return [Fill in this blank];
    }
}

public class B
{
    public C FirstC;
    public C SecondC;
}

public class C
{
    public ObservableCollection<D> Ds;
}

public class D
{
    public bool IsSelected;
}
```

So, I wanna to get all D which `IsSelected==true` (from Bs and both FirstC and SecondC results joined). So, how to fill the `<Query here>` part of `getSelectedCs()` in class A?

This is what I've done so far to fill in the blank:

```
return Bs.
    [Getting both FirstC and SecondC].
    SelectMany(x=>x.Ds).
    Where(x=>x.IsSelected);
```

Plus, I wanna do it in 1 lambda sentence (I can do it if it's using 2 sentences).

What should I write in `[Getting both FirstC and SecondC]`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<D> getSelectedDs()
{
     return Bs.SelectMany(b => b.FirstC.Ds.Union(b.SecondC.Ds))
              .Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
}
```

Comment: notice, that `Union` is a set operation and will ignore same objects. `new[]{1,1,1}.Union(new[]{1,2,3})` will return `1,2,3`. Might be the desired behavior.

Comment: Otherwise use `.Concat(...)` to concatenate and simply iterate through both sets.

Comment: yes,both of you are right. to use `Union` or `Contact` is depand on the @Mosess